# I add Struct Pointer inside the vector and Struct Value has been changed

Tags: c++, struct, raylib

I'm using raylib to make a little game. and here is the problem.

Struct Icon has Loc Struct that has two integer value.

When i put the Struct, Icon as a Pointer into Icons vector. value has been changed.

here is the capture of debuging.

[image]

[image]

and here is the full code.

```
// driver.cpp
void init() {

    InitWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Uvuntu");

    SetTargetFPS(30);

    map<string, Texture2D> mapset = loadAllImages();


    setCursor(mapset.find("cursor")->second);
    setIcons({ "File Exploer", mapset.find("icon_dir")->second, nullptr });
    setIcons({ "File Exploer", mapset.find("icon_dir")->second, nullptr });

    runIcons();
}
// icons.cpp
using namespace std;

vector<Icon*> icons;

int default_x = int(WINDOW_WIDTH  / 50);
int default_y = int(WINDOW_HEIGHT / 50);

int step = 128;

int icon_x = default_x;
int icon_y = default_y;

void setIcons(Icon icon) {
    Loc loc = { icon_x, icon_y };
    icon.loc = &loc;

    icon_y += step;
    if (icon_y > WINDOW_HEIGHT) {
        icon_y = default_y;
        icon_x += step;
    }

    cout << icon.loc->x << endl;
    cout << icon.loc->y << endl;

    icons.push_back(&icon);
}

void runIcons() {
    Loc loc = *icons.at(0)->loc;  // the problem...
    string name = to_string(loc.x) + ", " + to_string(loc.y);
    cout << name << endl;
}
// icon.cpp
using namespace std;

struct Icon {
    string name;
    Texture2D icon_img;
    Loc* loc;
};
// loc.cpp

struct Loc {
    int x, y;
};
```

Comment: why do you store pointers in the vector? `icon` is a local variable that ceases to exist when the function returns

Comment: `icon.loc = &loc;` is wrong for the same reason

Comment: Enable all warnings and use `-Werror`. [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: In C++, **automatic** storage duration, which is the storage of all local objects, the object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated at the end.  What you want is **dynamic** storage duration, such as used by `new`; or better yet use `std::make_unique<Icon>` with your `vector<std::unique_ptr<Icon>> icons;`.

Comment: @Roharui -- `void setIcons(Icon icon)` -- Are you using another computer language as a model in writing C++ code?  You are aware that passing variables this way in C++ makes a temporary copy of the variable?  You are not working on the original `Icon` that was passed, only a copy.  I know that other computer languages, that `Icon` is a reference to the original `Icon` that is passed, but that is not how C++ works.  If you are using another language as a model in writing C++ code, don't.  What you wind up with are 1) Buggy code, 2) Inefficient code, 3) Code that looks weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- you're perfectly correct... i'm not use to the C++. thank you for the support.